# How to decompose unitary quantum gate in current simulator or emulator?

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, quantum-algorithms

I have a question about how to decompose a unitary quantum gate in a currently existing simulator or emulator. I have read some papers about SK algorithm and other algorithms which aim to decompose unitary quantum gates. Is there any specific method to decompose a quantum gate in a currently existing simulator? Some papers about decomposition methods mention Trotter-Suzuki decomposition but I don't exactly know if this is true? To be more specific, what is the decomposition algorithm in Qiskit or Project Q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qiskit, the iso() function allows you to add a gate, defined by means of a unitary, to your quantum circuit:

https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.iso.html

The decomposition used in the iso() function was introduced by Iten et al. in https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06911.

Of course this is related to the circuit, not to the backend (which can be real or simulated).

Comment: So all the simulator or emulator decompose a unitary gate in that way? I mean, the decomposion strategy is same in existing simulators or emulators or it is depend on specific simulators or emulators? Thx

Comment: In Qiskit, you may either build the circuit from the scratch by adding gates, or by providing the unitary matrix of the circuit and decompose it using iso(). As I wrote in my answer, decomposition is independent on whether you want to run the circuit on a real backend or in a simulated one. Once you have the decomposition, then you choose the backend.

Comment: So after decompose it into CNOT and single qubit gate as the paper mentioned. How to decompose the single qubit gate into universal quantum gates set? like Clifford +T, Thx

Comment: Usually, you choose the universal quantum gate set depending on the backend you are using. For IBM Q backends, the most general single qubit gate is $U_3$ (https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/single-qubit-gates.html#7.-General-U-gates--). In Qiskit, to compile your circuit using specific gates (e.g., CNOT and $U_3$), you need to use the transpile() function: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html

Comment: So, the universal quantum gates  {Clifford +T} is not commonly used in any backend or simulated one anymore, right? I read the reference you sent, one U3 gate seems can represent any single qubit gate, However, in SK algorithm, by running the C++ code, the H and T gate grow exponentially. so if the basic gate set canbe {U3 and CNOT}, why we need {Clifford+T},like in SK-algorithm or some of its optimization.

Comment: What are SK algorithm and the C++ code you refer to? I have not such references, so I cannot help with your last question.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0505030.pdf, this paper is about THE SOLOVAY-KITAEV ALGORITHM, which told us a any unitary single gate can be decomposed into {Hadamard, Phase} with any accuracy  , the number of {Hadamard, Phase} grows exponentially as the  becomes accurate, and the result is approximated decomposition. However, in your reference, the U3 gate seems exacted decomposition which means only one U3 gate can be realized any unitary single gate. If so, why so many people still need approximated decomposition and optimize it to shorten the approximated sequence of {Hadamard, Phase}